# Is there a way to make certain applications hide as soon as they no longer become the active window?

Tags: macos, mac, applications, window-manager

I have a few application which I would really like it if they were to hide automatically instead of moving behind the new active window. It would be great if I could make some sort of daemon which automatically hides these application windows when they stop being the active window.

Googling this isn't bringing up anything useful and I imagine it's because I don't know how to phrase it. I have no idea how I'm best to achieve this, but if there's a way, I'd like to have a go.

I'm running MacOS Big Sur.

Does anyone know where I can start with this? If you could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: I remember way back when, reading about an App called [Quitter](https://marco.org/apps#quitter). I think it might do what you want

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the full solution you are looking for, but maybe I can help get the ball rolling on this. There is a hidden mode in mac os, "single app mode" whereas switching between apps auto hides the previous. You can enable this by typing in this command in the terminal.
`defaults write com.apple.dock single-app -bool true` then do 
`killall Dock` to restart the dock and commit the changes.

if you wish to undo this command replace true with false. Another suggestion, if you hold the option key down while clicking (switching) on from app to app via the dock the previous app will automatically be hidden. This is also true if you have a window in the front and you option click the desktop in the background, will instantly hide the frontmost app window.